# Exclude code from test coverage calculation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

There are quite a few questions about this with various hacks, but none cover this use case. I have some code that will never fail in a `try` `catch` block

```
        try {
            stringBytes = value.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
        }
```

UTF-8 is always supported, so I can't make this fail, but due to the fact the catch block is never hit I can't get 100% code coverage either.

I could change the code so that I can change the encoding type, but this just opens up a potential bug that doesn't currently exist.

NB: This code needs to work with GWT 2.6.1 which doesn't support `getBytes(Charset charset)`

Is there something I can do to get 100% coverage?

Comment: You can inject your implementation of value that throws exception in `getBytes`. If you can't do that easily, move the validation logic to another class that receives the value.